# How to use godot 3d grid?

Tags: 3d, grid, godot

So I am trying to make a card game in godot, and I want to drag and drop cards on a gameboard (rigid body) using raycast. So far it is working, but my question is: how could I align the cards, so they won't overlap or spawn outside the gameboard. I have figured out that I need to use a grid, but I don't really know how it does work.

I have attached my code and a screenshot with my nodes:

```
func place():
var rayOrigin = Vector3()
var rayEnd = Vector3()
var cardbase = preload("res://Cards/CardBase.tscn")
var card = preload("res://Cards/3dcard.tscn")
var cardscript = preload("res://Cards/3dcard.gd")
var camera = get_tree().get_root().find_node("Camera", true, false)
if Input.is_action_just_released("leftclick") && cardinhand == 1 :
    var space_state = get_world().direct_space_state
    var mouse_position = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    rayOrigin = camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
    rayEnd = rayOrigin + camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_position) * 2000000000
    var intersection = space_state.intersect_ray(rayOrigin, rayEnd)
    if not  intersection.empty(): 
        board = 1
        var addcard = card.instance()
        addcard.Cardname = cardnm
        add_child(addcard)
        addcard.translation = Vector3(intersection.position.x*1.01,intersection.position.y,intersection.position.z)
    cardinhand = 0
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnPPb.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `GridMap` and that is not how you would use a `GridMap` if you were going to.

The primary use of a `GridMap` is to design scenarios. Think of it as a 3D `TileMap`. You would have a `MeshLibrary` (which is the `TileSet` counterpart) use it to place meshes in the different cells of the grids.

---

Instead of using `GridMap`, do this:

- Convert the position to the local space of the board.
- There do the grid adjustment (this is dividing by the cell size, rounding, and multiplying by the cell size again).
- Then convert the position back to global space.
- Place the card on that global position.

*I'm assuming you don't need to worry about orientation. If you do, then I'll suggest creating a `Basis` and then a `Transform` from the `Basis`.*

Something like this:

```
var grid_size := Vector3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)

# ...

# check the ray collided with the rigid_body board
if intersection.collider == rigid_body:

    # ...

    addcard.global_transform.origin = rigid_body.to_global(
        grid_size * (
            rigid_body.to_local(intersection.position) / grid_size
        ).floor()
    )
```

*Note that I'm assuming a variable `rigid_body` that holds a reference to the board.*

---

By the way, you are working on 3D, you can get the current camera with `get_viewport().get_camera()`.